# Iterating through a xml is not working in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

My XML:

```
<animals>
  <animal name="fox" fullname="fullfox"></animal>
  <animal name="dog" fullname="halfdog"><food>milk</food><food>rice</food><food>meat</food>   </animal>
  <animal name="cow" fullname="doublecow"><food>grass</food></animal>
  <animal name="blabla" fullname="fullbla"></animal>
</animals>
```

I'm trying to parse this XML to get same XML as output.

```
doc    = ET.parse("an.xml")
root = doc.getroot() #Returns the root element for this tree.
root_new  = ET.Element("animals") 
for child in root:
    name = child.attrib['name']
    fullname = child.attrib['fullname']

for g in root.findall("*/food"):
    animal    = ET.SubElement(root_new, "animal") 
    food     = ET.SubElement(animal, "food")   
    food.text = g.text
    animal.set("name",name)               
    animal.set("fullname",fullname) 

tree = ET.ElementTree(root_new)
tree.write(sys.stdout)
```

But am getting only last value

```
<animals>
  <animal fullname="fullbla" name="blabla"><food>milk</food></animal>
  <animal fullname="fullbla" name="blabla"><food>rice</food></animal>
  <animal fullname="fullbla" name="blabla"><food>meat</food></animal>
  <animal fullname="fullbla" name="blabla"><food>grass</food></animal>
</animals>
```

And food node also wrong, how to iterate exactly like my input XML?

Comment: You should group together the `food` tags that are children of an object. Try to iterate over the animals and for each animal iterate over the foods.

Comment: i try that way tooo..but same :(

Comment: But no one can answer exactly , the output xml indendation :( , all xml here, which i accepted also coming in one line :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code should look like this

```
doc    = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = doc.getroot() #Returns the root element for this tree.
root_new  = ET.Element("animals") 
for child in root:
    name             = child.attrib['name']
    fullname         = child.attrib['fullname']
    animal    = ET.SubElement(root_new, "animal") 
    animal.set("name",name)               
    animal.set("fullname",fullname) 

    for g in child.findall("food"):
        food = ET.SubElement(animal, "food")   
        food.text = g.text

tree = ET.ElementTree(root_new)
tree.write(sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a nested loop:

```
for child in root:
    name             = child.attrib['name']
    fullname         = child.attrib['fullname']
    # create "animal" here
    animal    = ET.SubElement(root_new, "animal") 
    animal.set("name",name)               
    animal.set("fullname",fullname)
    for g in child.findall("food"):
        # create "food" here
        food     = ET.SubElement(animal, "food")   
        food.text = g.text
```

Comment: <animals><animal fullname="fullfox" name="fox" /><animal fullname="halfdog" name="dog" /><animal fullname="doublecow" name="cow" /><animal fullname="fullbla" name="blabla" /></animals> : this is out put...hmmm wrong one bro :(

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.  The first is your indentation - I assume those are meant to be nested loops.  The second problem is that you're using `root.findall`, which means that you are getting all `food` items regardless of which node they are in.  Try this instead:

```
...
for child in root:
    name = child.attrib['name']
    fullname = child.attrib['fullname']
    animal = ET.SubElement(root_new, 'animal')
    for g in child.findall("food"):
        food = ET.SubElement(animal, "food")   
        food.text = g.text
        animal.set('name', name)               
        animal.set('fullname', fullname)
```

Comment: animal should be created before the child loop

Comment: out put is only this , how u said its working :)
  : <animals />